# Commitment Games, Nash Equilibria and Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibria

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Are all Nash equilibria found from the strategic form of a commitment game all subgame perfect Nash equilibria (SPNE)?

Comment: It depends on what the extensive form game looks like.